# vim not working after upgrading to mac os x 10.13.1 high sierra

Tags: mac, vim

I upgraded to mac os high sierra 10.13.1, and now when I try to run vim, I get this message.

dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim Reason: image not found Abort trap: 6

What might I need to do to get vim working again?

I believe I have xcode installed, and also brew, the missing package manager for mac os, if that helps.

Answer (score 14):

Did you install vim with homebrew?

Update homebrew and vim.
`brew update`
`brew upgrade vim`

(I'd recommend upgrading everything installed with homebrew `brew upgrade` - **but** be ready for things to break.)

You might also need to unlink and re-link vim.

**On a 2nd look**, it looks like it's due to broken ruby, only re-linking ruby might fix it, but upgrade is still a good idea. `brew link --overwrite ruby`

My homebrew packages often get broken by a macOS upgrade, it seems best to upgrade everything at the same time.

Comment: `brew upgrade vim` did the job

Comment: If you have problems with ownership of `/usr/local`, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459152/cant-chown-usr-local-for-homebrew-in-osx-10-13-high-sierra).

Answer (score 4):

Previous answers did not work for me. 
(did not try installing from source, didn't want to "own" my macvim at that level)

This did work:

`brew uninstall --purge macvim
brew install macvim`

Comment: This finally did the trick for me (using vim, not macvim).

Answer (score 2):

All that stuff didn't quite work for me.

But uninstalling and reinstalling Vim worked.

```
brew uninstall vim
brew install vim
```

Comment: Do this one! It works!

Answer (score 1):

1. `$ brew doctor` - let me know I needed to install xcode and fix my path to sbin
2. `$ xcode-select --install` (installs xcode)
3. I also had to add brew's sbin to my path in my .zshrc
4. `$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` (fixes path)
5. `$ source ~/.zshrc`- (refresh .zshrc)
6. `$ brew install macvim`
7. `$ brew upgrade`

That did the trick. Now vim opens with `$ vim`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$ brew update

$ brew upgrade macvim
```

actual command output:

```
[bin]$ brew upgrade macvim
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
macvim 8.0-142
==> Upgrading macvim --with-override-system-vim
==> Downloading https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/archive/snapshot-142.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://codeload.github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/tar.gz/snapshot-142
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-multibyte --with-macarchs=x86_64 --enable-perlinterp --enable-rubyinterp --enable-tclinterp --enable-ter
==> make
  /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-142: 2,147 files, 34.2MB, built in 3 minutes 15 seconds
[bin]$
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the previous answer, and I got an error while upgrading vim

```
brew upgrade vim
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated Homebrew from 62f85cfa to af8f8f11.
Updated 1 tap (caskroom/cask).

Error: vim: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/vim.rb:100: syntax error, unexpected <<
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
  ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/vim.rb:101: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/vim.rb:103: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/vim.rb:105: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
```

But I found using vim in system did work.

```
brew uninstall --force vim
```

The path is

```
where vi
/usr/bin/vi
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a conflict on vim version you have to run `unlik macvim` before installing. These steps worked for me.

`brew uninstall vim`

`brew unlink macvim`

`brew install vim`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Check brew..

```
brew doctor
brew update
```

Download Xcode updates just in case..

```
xcode-select --install
```

Change your path and use an updated VIM image..

```
brew unlink vim
brew upgrade macvim

vim
```

VIM version 8.1.577

Curious if you can do this in macports?

Answer (score -1):

I have tried brew update && brew upgrade vim, but hit the same issue. Installing from source solved this issue eventually.

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim
./configure
make install
```